# What is the most elegant way to run a lambda for each element of a Java 8 stream and simultaneously count how many elements were processed?

Tags: java-8

What is the most elegant way to run a lambda for each element of a Java 8 stream and simultaneously count how many items were processed, assuming I want to process the stream only once and not mutate a variable outside the lambda?

Comment: What do you mean by process? `map()` or `forEach()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be tempting to use

```
long count = stream.peek(action).count();
```

and it may appear to work. However, `peek`’s action will only be performed when an element is being processed, but for some streams, the count may be available without processing the elements. Java 9 is going to take this opportunity, which makes the code above fail to perform `action` for some streams.

You can use a `collect` operation that doesn’t allow to take short-cuts, e.g.

```
long count = stream.collect(
    Collectors.mapping(s -> { action.accept(s); return s; }, Collectors.counting()));
```

or

```
long count = stream.collect(Collectors.summingLong(s -> { action.accept(s); return 1; }));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a reduce operation of some sort, something like this:

```
 int howMany = Stream.of("a", "vc", "ads", "ts", "ta").reduce(0, (i, string) -> {
        if (string.contains("a")) {
            // process a in any other way
            return i+1;
        }
        return i;
    }, (left, right) -> null); // override if parallel stream required

    System.out.println(howMany);
```

Comment: The question doesn’t mention conditional processing, but if this is intended, a `filter` before counting would do. Besides—what’s stopping you from specifying the straight-forward merging function `(left, right) -> left+right` rather than `(left, right) -> null`? It doesn’t create any harm for sequential streams…

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `peek` function, as it returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

elements 
  .stream()
  .forEach(doSomething())
  .peek(elem -> counter.incrementAndGet());

int elementsProcessed = counter.get();
```

Comment: *and not mutate a variable outside the lambda*

Comment: Besides the fact that using `peek` for this purpose is not recommended, it doesn’t even compile, if you try to chain a `peek` *after* the terminal `forEach` operation.

Comment: `forEach` returns void and the suggested code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are [lazily evaluated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) and therefore processed in a single step, combining all intermediate operations when a final operation is called, no matter how many operations you perform over them.

This way, you don't have to worry because your stream will be processed at once. But the best way to perform some operation on each stream's element and count the number of elements processed depends on your goal.
Anyway, the two examples below don't mutate a variable to perform that count.

Both examples create a Stream of Strings, perform a trim() on each String to remove blank spaces and then, filter the Strings that have some content.

## Example 1

*Uses the peek method to perform some operation over each filtered string. In this case, just print each one. Finally, it just uses the count() to get how many Strings were processed.*

```
Stream<String> stream = 
       Stream.of(" java", "", " streams", "   are", " lazily ", "evaluated"); 
long count = stream
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .count();

System.out.printf(
      "\nNumber of non-empty strings after a trim() operation: %d\n\n", count);
```

## Example 2

*Uses the collect method after filtering and mapping to get all the processed Strings into a List. By this way, the List can be printed separately and the number of elements got from list.size()*

```
Stream<String> stream = 
    Stream.of(" java", "", " streams", "   are", " lazily ", "evaluated"); 
List<String> list = stream
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

list.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.printf(
      "\nNumber of non-empty strings after a trim() operation: %d\n\n", list.size());
```